# Pass attributes to child

Tags: lightning-aura-components, attribute

I have 2 components, 1 parent and 1 child.

**c:parentComponent**

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="passToChild" type="String" required="false" description="" access="private"/>

    <c:childComponent valueFromParent="{! v.passToChild }"

</aura:component>
```

**c:childComponent**

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="valueFromParent" type="String" required="false" description="" access="private"/>

    Some text

</aura:component>
```

I want to get the value of the passToChild attribute and pass it to the child component  for futher processing. However, I am getting an error.

```
Failed to save undefined: No ATTRIBUTE named valueFromParent found: Source
```

I tried creating an attribute with that name but it still shows the error. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attribute `valueFromParent` in `c:childComponent` has `private` value of access attribute. It is visible only inside this component. Change it to `public`, or just remove `access` attribute

**c:childComponent**

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="valueFromParent" type="String" required="false" description="" access="public"/>
    Some text
</aura:component>
```

Refer to [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/access_attr.htm)

> Accessing a private attribute returns undefined unless you reference
>   it from the component in which it’s declared.

Comment: Oh my god you are a legend! I thought I was doing a wrong call only to find out that it should be public instead. Thanks man!